# How to synchronize Magento Cloud environments?

Tags: magento2, database, server-setup, magento-cloud

I have three environments, **Production, Staging,** and **Integration**, I'd like to sync Integration DB and Code as its parent environment, which is Staging.

How could I sync the database and the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Magento Cloud CLI to do it, you just need to change to your **integration** branch and run it:

### Sync Database

```
magento-cloud sync data
```

### Sync Code

```
magento-cloud sync code
```

### Sync Media

```
zip -r -9 var/media.zip pub/media/ -x 'pub/media/catalog/tmp' -x 'pub/media/catalog/product/cache/' -x 'pub/media/tmp/'
```

Move the zip to your local machine and transfer it to your integration env.

```
magento-cloud scp -r remote:var/media.zip ./ -e staging
magento-cloud scp -r ./media.zip remote:var/ -e integration
```

Comment: My current branch is integration (In Pro plan), it shows error [ClientException]
  Client error response [url] https://ap-3.magento.cloud/api/projects/xxxxxx/environments/integration/synchronize [status code] 400 [reason phrase] Bad Request [message] The server could not comply with the request since it is either malformed or otherwise incorrect. [detail] {"error":"Can not synchronize data with parent environment."} [title] Bad Request. 


Is this command only works for Starter plan?